# Omifaces @Push and Spring integration

Tags: spring, jsf, cdi, omnifaces

I have an application with Spring 4.x and Primefaces 7. Now I need to introduce push functionality. Starting from Primefaces 7, push function was removed (in previous releases it was provided by atmosphere framework). Now in release notes of version 7, the developer team suggests using Omnifaces or JFS 2.3. I tried to integrate Omnifaces but, if I understand correctly, the `@Push` tag is interpreted by CDI only and ignored by Spring. I've all my beans and services managed with Spring. Is there a way to make `@Push` to works with Spring?

For JFS 2.3 I've the same problem.

Comment: Create one cdi bean that is nothing more than a wrapper in which you programmatically retrieve the spring managed service

Comment: Can you provide an example please?

Comment: No, since I don't use Spring, I use JavaEE (and asking almost 4 months after being silent is not a real incentive either...) But there are other Q/A in Stackoverflow if I'm right